# Using almost same view for editing and viewing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So my question is about handling both editing and viewing document data in same view. Basically, I have a view that can view document data. It has necessary fields and can show text information for user. How can I, guys, edit this document using this one view?
So seems like I need to pass some flag that indicates "editing" or "viewing" mode and show edit textboxes or just text.
Any techniques, methods to achieve this? Could you, guys, advice me something? Any blog posts, articles, manuals will be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance guys!
P.S.: it is ASP .NET MVC3 application (with Razor view engine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually accomplish this using two differant actions (details and edit). You would decorate your actions using AcceptVerbs. POST vs. GET in this case. You can create a single 'partial view' that is returned by both actions. Its behavior (readonly / editable) will be dictated by the action that returns the view.

There is a very straight forward tutorial covering just this here:

[CRUD](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm)

[Reusing Views (Partial View)](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part7.htm)

Comment: Thanks, Nick! But what is about view? That logic is keep?

Comment: @kseen Are you asking what the "About" view is? You can write a single view and reuse it. These are called partial views in ASP.NET MVC. The section of the article I added will give you step by step instructions on doing exaclty what you are asking. Its a very common task

Comment: I also added link to the section of this tutorial that explains Partial Views

Comment: Nick, I just don't want to make two different views: one for viewing (with just text) and one for editing (with edit boxes). I just want use one.